# Why does the loss function output NaN after increasing Epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

While I was learning TensorFlow (Version 1) through text, I ran into the following problem:

```py
# Generate data
xy, labels = make_circles(n_samples=200, noise=0.1, random_state=717)
features = xy

num_hidden1 = 10
num_hidden2 = 5

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))
rand_init = tf.random_normal_initializer(seed=624)

# Hidden Layer 1
hidden1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x, num_hidden1, 
                                            activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid,
                                            weights_initializer=rand_init,
                                            biases_initializer=rand_init)

# Hidden Layer 2
hidden2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(hidden1, num_hidden2,
                                            activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid,
                                            weights_initializer=rand_init,
                                            biases_initializer=rand_init)

# Output Layer
yhat =  tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(hidden2, 1,
                                          activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid,
                                          weights_initializer=rand_init,
                                          biases_initializer=rand_init)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(-y * tf.log(yhat) - (1-y) * tf.log(1-yhat))

# Prepare algorithm
MaxEpochs = 2500
lr = 0.1
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# Shuffle data
np.random.seed(7382)
idx = np.arange(0, len(features))
np.random.shuffle(idx)
shuffled_features = features[idx]
shuffled_labels = labels[idx]

# Stochastic method
batch_size = 25
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for epoch in range(MaxEpochs):
    if epoch % 500 == 0:
        loss_val = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: features, y: labels.reshape(-1,1)})
        plot_model(sess, yhat, xy, labels, f_fn, 'Epoch {}\n (loss={:1.2f})'.format(epoch, loss_val))
    for x_batch, y_batch in generate_batches(batch_size, shuffled_features, shuffled_labels):
        sess.run(train, feed_dict={x: x_batch, y: y_batch.reshape(-1,1)})
loss_val = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: features, y: labels.reshape(-1,1)})
print(loss_val)
plot_model(sess, yhat, xy, labels, f_fn, 'Epoch {}\n (loss={:1.2f})'.format(epoch+1, loss_val))
```

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/contour.py:1483: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.self.zmax = float(z.max())
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/contour.py:1134: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater over = np.nonzero(lev > self.zmax)[0]
```

The example worked fine when testing with `MaxEpoch=20` and it was increased to 2500 in order to show a case of overfitting with `loss=0.18`; however, when I run it, the loss function starts outputting NaN after ~400 epoch.

Is the example from text outdated or is this supposed to be a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You should be decaying your learning rate as you run for longer iterations. Most likely your learning rate of 0.1 is too high for 2500 epochs. You can try a lower lr and run 2500 epochs to demonstrate over fitting on training data.

Comment: Does the AdamOptimizer not adjust the learning rate as it goes through the training iterations ?

Comment: It does, but that adjustment per parameter may not be enough to offset a high initial learning rate. It really varies from problem to problem.